# prepare a json object in view to pass the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-2

i have a tree that has a ul li HTML structure .

In every li there is a span that contains the node name of the tree.

I have to make a json object after reading the tree it should look like some thing in this manner

```
        this.orgStructureId = null; 
        this.name = null;
        this.nodeList = null; 
        this.parent = null;
        this.list = null;
```

i am not sure that it will be the structure but some thing similar.so how can i make this object do you need any more inputs for making the json object.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9itqx.jpg
Tree sample snap shot

Comment: I have not tried to many things since i am not able to make the the structure of json object so that than i could initialize it and use it. to start it can you send me the json structure that it should look like as my tree i am adding a snap shot of my tree

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = {};
$('li').each(function(){
    json[this.innerHTML] = null;
})
```

Then you just need to serialize it

Comment: check the snap shot and than suggest me as my tree can got 4-5 level so this function will not do for me

Comment: I'm reminded now about recursion and DOM walk / DOM tree for some reason

Comment: yup you are making sense for what you are saying so how to achieve this can you provide me the sample structure  for it some piece of code explains the json object prpearation

Answer (score 0):

### Tree is generated on the server

If your tree is generated on the server side, you could as well add its JSON string to your HTML and use that preprepared JSON data instead of generating in on the client side...

```
<ul id="TreeRoot" data="{ name: 'Some name', ... }">
    <li>...</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Then just call

```
var data = $.parseJSON($("#TreeRoot").attr("data"));
```

and you'll get your JSON data to send to the server. But there will be another obstacle... passing that data to controller action.

I suggest you read [this blog post about sending JSON data](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html), that will make your life even easier...

### Tree is generated on the client

In case your tree is generated/edited on the client by users you will have no other option but either:

- traverse DOM elements of your hierarchy data and generate JSON
- generate JSON data while user creates the tree and have it prepared on the go and use the end result

I'd probably go with the second one, because you'll be manipulating data already anyway. So why not generate HTML nodes and populate variables as well.